# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

[Moderator election #4](https://pets.stackexchange.com/election/4) on Pets — your "graduation" election! — has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Elmy]

[image: Harry V.]

[image: Journeyman Geek]

They will be forming [the new moderation crew](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking lila, who will be stepping down after serving as a pro-tem moderator for the past 2 years:

[image: lila]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/election/4) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5510817226162176).

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators! Here's to many years of happy moderating 